# How to implement fixed parameters in caffe?

Tags: deep-learning, caffe, pycaffe

Suppose there are parameters in the network I would like to change manually in pycaffe, rather than update automatically by the solver. For example, suppose we would like to penalize dense activations, this can be implemented as an additional loss layer. Across the training process, we would like to change the strength of this penalty by multiplying the loss with a coefficient that evolves in a pre-specified way. What would be a good way to do this in caffe? Is it possible to specify this in the prototxt definition? In the pycaffe interface?

Update: I suppose setting `lr_mult` and `decay_mult` to 0 might be a solution, but seems like a clumsy one. Maybe a `DummyDataLayer` providing the parameters as a blob would be a better option. But there is so little documentation that it's quite a struggle to write for someone new to caffe

Comment: it's unclear what you are trying to do. Can you please clarify your question?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I have added an example

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this is a trivial question, but just in case someone else might be interested, here is a successful implementation I ended up using

In the layer proto def, set `lr_mult` and `decay_mult` to 0, which means that we neither want to learn or decay the parameters. Use `filler` to set initial values. To change the parameters in python during training of the network, use a statement like
`net.param['name'][index].data[...] = something`